# Getting JSON with jQuery and creating lists with click events calling more jQuery and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two elements on my page:

```
<ul id="VerticalMenu></ul>
<ul id="AccordionMenu"></ul>
```

I'm calling some JSON with jQuery and loading elements in the `div`s. I'm curious if there are things I can be doing more efficiently, and better ways to use selectors and JSON.

```
$().ready(function() {
    //Load sections
    GetCarlineSections(_BucketID);
});

function GetCarlineSections(bucketID) {
    //Get section json list
    $.ajax(
    { 
        type: "POST",
        url: _ApplicationRootURL + 'GetChildBucketList', //Call the ActionResult to return the JSON object
        data: 'parentID=' + bucketID,
        success: function (sections) { //'sections' is an array of JSON objects returned by GetChildBucketList
            $(sections).each(function () {
                $('#VerticalMenu') //Append each item to the #VerticalMenu <ul>
                    .append(
                        $('<li/>') //Append a new <li> element to <ul> #VerticalMenu
                        .addClass('Section')
                        .html(
                            $('<h4/>') //Create a new <h4> inside of the <li>
                            .addClass(this.BucketName)
                            .html(this.BucketName)
                            .click({ parentID: this.BucketID }, function (event) { //Attach a click event to the <h4> element
                                $('#AccordionMenu').empty();
                                GetSectionSubSections(event.data.parentID); //Event.data.parentID is the id of the bucket represented by this <h4> element
                            })
                        )
                    );
            });
        }
    });
}

function GetSectionSubSections(bucketID) {
    $.ajax(
    { 
        type: "POST",
        url: _ApplicationRootURL + 'GetChildBucketList',
        data: 'parentID=' + bucketID,
        success: function (SubSections) { //SubSections are the children buckets of Section, local var bucketID
            $(SubSections).each(function () {
                $('#AccordionMenu')
                    .append(
                        $('<li/>')
                        .addClass('SubSection')
                        .html(
                            $('<h4/>')
                            .addClass(this.SEOURLName)
                            .html(this.BucketName)
                            .click({ parentID: this.BucketID }, function (event) { //Eventdata parentID passes the SubSectionID to the event object
                                GetSubSectionHeadlines(this, event.data.parentID)
                            })
                        )
                    );
            });
        }
    });
}

function GetSubSectionHeadlines(parentElement, SubSectionID) {
    //Get the Headlines based on the parent SubSection
    $(parentElement).after($('<ul/>').addClass(parentElement.className));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _ApplicationRootURL + 'GetChildBucketList',
        data: 'parentID=' + SubSectionID,
        success: function (Headlines) {
            $(Headlines).each(function () {
                $('ul.' + parentElement.className).prepend(
                    $('<li/>')
                        .html(this.BucketName)
                )
            })
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two small nickpicks at the start:

- Empty HTML lists (`ul`, `ol`) are strictly spoken invalid. They should contain at least one list item. That said, I believe there is no browser limitation or other technical reason an empty list shouldn't work.
- It is custom for the names of functions, variables and object fields in JavaScript to be written with a small letter at the beginning.

You can optimize adding the list item to the list, by using `.map()` to create the items and appending them all at once.

```
$('#VerticalMenu') 
  .append(
    $(sections).map(function () {
      $('<li/>') 
      // ...
    })
  );
```

BTW, since sections is an array of simple JavaScript objects and not DOM objects it's a bit weird to wrap them in a jQuery object (`$(sections).each(...)`), because jQuery unwraps them immediately anyway. You should use `$.each(sections, ... )` (or `$.map(sections, ... )`) instead.

You are assigning all items in your lists the same class (`Section` and `SubSection` respectively). Unless you remove the class later, this is usually a sign of wrong CSS design. If you leave out the class, then instead of the selector `.Section { ... }` you can use a descendent selector: `#VerticalMenu li { ... }`.

One last thing: The use of `h4` elements seems wrong to me. Either this is a menu, then you shouldn't be using header elements at all, or the items in AccordionMenu are subheadlines and be using `h5` instead.

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. Don't feel bad about being nitpicky, it's that kind of stuff that makes for strong development.